# How to make field validation works correctly on custom policy customized ui?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-b2c

Using Custom Policy in Azure AD B2C, trying to update UI adding Custom UI (which I created from scratch) and just added id=api tag inside the HTML, the UI is reflecting correctly but inputs are showing error messages by default on the first load, how can I make validation on fields work as default UI?

```
 <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
        <LoadUri>https://XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/templates/custom-ui.html</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.0.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName"></Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>
 </ContentDefinitions>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement CSS to show and hide for the validation error block.

This is how it usually get implemented:

```
.attrEntry .error.itemLevel, .attrEntry .helpText,.attrEntry .tiny {
  display: none!important;    }
```

You can check it in below github repo for further reference:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-external-identities-woodgrove-demo/blob/2b5110c25d1a626bf9b9ac27ecaaabad8b4bccf4/Templates/dist/unified_1.html

https://woodgrovegroceriesb2cdemo.azurewebsites.net/Account/LogIn

[Azure AD B2C Custom UI error labels shown on first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296225/azure-ad-b2c-custom-ui-error-labels-shown-on-first-load/52306776)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Start with the default pages here which contain all the CSS to make our pages look right. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom-dynamic

Comment: Did the fix by overwriting message inside the policy