# Custom policy showing error labels on page load

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I saw a question similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296225/azure-ad-b2c-custom-ui-error-labels-shown-on-first-load). I'm facing the same issue with my policy too.

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
        <LoadUri>https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/b2c/signup</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:selfasserted:1.1.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account sign up page</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="signup_en" />
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
      </ContentDefinition>
```

Validation errors are showing on the page load itself. As the solution of the question says hide that using CSS, but is there any other solution to fix this from B2C without using style.?

Comment: Start with the default pages here which contain all the CSS to make our pages look [right](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization)

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity But i need to use custom UI

Comment: Alex, does the validation error messages disappear after the page loads completely?

Comment: @ChristopherNorris No, it is not disappearing after page loads completely.

Comment: The link I provided above is related to custom UI only

Comment: @Alex, are you able to provide a link to the CSS for review? Generally, I would be looking for any CSS that interacts with .error .pageLevel or general divs.

Comment: @ChristopherNorris I'm not using any css, it is a plane html having only the "api" div.